# how to download file from heroku with git

Tags: php, git, heroku

How can I download my currently changed file from heroku server?

I built a PHP application that is running on Heroku.

If I use `$ git clone git@heroku.com:myappli.git -o heroku` then would this upload my original project files from my computer to the Heroku server?

If I use `$ heroku git:clone -a myappli` then would this download the whole project files to my computer?

How can I download my file (logfilled.txt) from the Heroku server?

Comment: If you had your application putting data in `logfilled.txt` then you have no way of accessing it.

Comment: Really? There is no way to access the data from my file? What can I do now to get the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most PaaS providers, Heroku [does not provide a persistent filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem):

> ### Ephemeral filesystem
>
> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted.

This means that every time you deploy files that you have created or modified will be lost or reverted to the last committed state. It is probably not a great idea to create your own log files on Heroku.

However, Heroku automaticaly [logs anything printed to standard out or standard error](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#writing-to-your-log):

> ### Writing to your log
>
> Anything written to standard out (`stdout`) or standard error (`stderr`) is captured into your logs. This means that you can log from anywhere in your application code with a simple output statement.

Logs [may be retrieved using the `heroku logs` command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-retrieval).

Try using PHP's [`error_log`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.error-log.php) function  to write your logs. If you are using a logging library like [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) you may have to configure it to output to `php://stderr` instead of to a file.

Finally, you could write to an arbitrary file like `logfilled.txt` and make that accessible via HTTP, then download it using a regular web browser, `wget`, `curl`, or any other tool. Note that you will almost certainly want to build some authentication around this; using Heroku's logging facility is a much better option.